# How do I prevent my debug build and release build from using the same Keychain data?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I currently have a debug version of my app on my device and the release version from the App Store, both have different product bundle ids where debug has “.debug” appended. They are both using the same keychain data, eg if I set the value for “email” on one, it shows up on the other. I am currently using the KeychainSwift library.

Is there anyway to separate the keychain stores between the two? Or should I just prefix the keys in the debug build with, say, “debug_”?

Comment: Keychain is not shared between apps unless those apps are in the same Access Group, did you accidentally put these two apps in same Access Group?

Comment: Use different bundle ids for your two builds. It would also separate your app into two apps which could further help you.

Comment: @ZonilyJame reread my first sentence.

Comment: @kubrickG thanks for the suggestion, will check later today and post an update

Comment: @kubrickG Oh, yep both have same access group.

Answer (score 2):

You should edit your entitlements file with different values for your environments, for example:
[image]

But that value could be "com.you.app.debug" if you are distributing your development version.